# Loop stopped working

Tags: php, loop

I have a huge issue and I broke my had trying to find the correct solution. I have a following loop code. This loop is inside my page-product.php file:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'colour' );
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
<section class="colour__chart">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="color-chart">
               <h2>Colour Chart</h2>
                <?
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'colour' );
if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach( $terms as $term ){

        echo get_field( 'name', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ); 

        echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">';
        echo '<div class="color-chart__item" style="background-color:' . get_field( 'colour_acf', 'colour_' . $term->term_id ) . '"></div>';
        echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>' ;
        echo '</div>' ;
    }
}
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and everything worked great before today. Suddenly the loop stopped working and instead of its correct displaying in the front-end I see only this text:

```
'; echo '
'; echo '
' . $term->name . '

' ; echo '
```

I've attached a screenshot also.
Would appreciate any help.[image]

Comment: did you update php?  Maybe try changing `<h2>color chart</h2 <?` to`<h2>color chart</h2 <?php`

Comment: @rudtek yeah that helped! Thanks a lot my friend. Please, post it as a separate comment so I could mark it as a solved.

Comment: done.  Thanks, let me know if there's anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `<?` was once a valid php opener, you should be using `<?php`.

Try changing this line:

```
           <h2>Colour Chart</h2>
            <?
```

to

```
           <h2>Colour Chart</h2>
            <?php
```

That should allow the php to be read correctly.